# JavaFX and CSS RadioButton styling

Tags: css, javafx, styles

I'm improving the graphical side of one of my programs and I'm currently trying to outline a SELECTED radio button in CSS, but it seems impossible to do so.
The odd thing is that this:

```
.radio-button .radio:hover {
    -fx-border-color: #15171c; /*gives the button a square border*/
    -fx-border-radius: 130px;  /*rounds the border around the button, "faking" a nice round outline*/
}
```

works just fine [result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LBDd.jpg ], but this:

```
.radio-button .radio:selected {
    -fx-border-color: #15171c;
    -fx-border-radius: 130px;
}
```

doesn't work. I can actually make a nice outline appear whenever I'm HOVERING over my radio buttons, but it seems impossible to give those buttons a permanent outline whenever they are SELECTED.

And the other thing that's bugging me is that this:

```
.radio-button:selected {
    -fx-border-color: #15171c;
    -fx-border-radius: 130px;
}
```

actually works [result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evUCy.jpg ]. The only problem is that "radio-button" refers to the radio button AND the label associated with it, and the outline wraps around both of those elements, which is clearly not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to give a selected button a permanent outline?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.radio-button:selected .radio`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it out as soon as I can.